# Where are the Cybertorso rules?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

This may be a silly question, but I'm seriously having issues finding more about cybertorsos.

I know that cybertorsos do exist, and they are somewhat needed for someone that relies on cyberlimbs, but I can't find any descriptions for them besides "they are actually a shell". I also found price/essence costs, but no actual description for them!

I tried to look for them on the Core Rulebook and on the Augmentation supplement, but didn't find anything more than a few passages about how they are needed for limbs or which NPCs have them and which don't. Googling around didn't help, me either.

So, what exactly are cybertorsos? Is there any place where I can find more about them?

I'm using Shadowrun 4th Edition.

Comment: I could be wrong, but they simply add a health box, no?

Comment: @ShadowKras I wish I knew! Seems like it is something like that, but I was unable to find a "Cybertorsos work like this" section on the books.

Comment: I answered with all the relevant rules about them i could find. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### They follow the standard rules for cyberlimbs.

On the Corebook (p.343), the rules for cyberlimbs are:

- They add an *extra condition monitor box* to your character.
- They have a *Capacity*, allowing your to implant other cyberwares within (like a **Cyber Holster**).
- They have their *own attributes* that replaces your own when used for tests. So, if you are trying to hold or breath you could use your cybertorso's Body rating.

There are also extra rules for cybertorsos among other cyberwares, as requeriments.

The **Articulated Weapon Arm** (Augmentation p.43), for instance, requires a cybertorso to be implanted first.

An **External Mount** (Augmentation p.43) also requires either a cyberarm or cybertorso to be implanted.

Also, without a *cybertorso*, the **maximum enhancement rating on your standard cyberlimbs is limited to 3** (Corebook p.343):

> Cyberlimbs come in two distinct types: standard and customized.
>
> **Standard limbs**: These prosthetics are basic off-the-shelf models.
> All standard cyberlimbs come with Body, Strength, and Agility attributes
> of 3. These values can only be augmented by cyberlimb enhancements.
> On standard cyberlimbs, **a cybertorso is required to have
> cyberlimb enhancements with a rating higher than 3**.

So, even the simplest of *cybertorsos* will allow you to obtain non-customized cyberlimbs of ratings higher than 3, up to your augmented limit. Otherwise, your maximum Strenght, Body and Agility is limited to 6 (3 base, 3 enhancement).

Comment: It's a bit unfortunate that such a important part of shadowrun (cyber stuff) was left scattered all around like this... Still, thank you for digging this up!

Comment: The main rules are on the corerule book though, page 343. They are a cyberlimb like the others.

Comment: By the way, the cyberskull also follows those rules. I dont see much use for the enhanced attributes on your head though. But the extra condition monitor box is useful.

Comment: Good to know! However, I'm still clueless about how they _look_ like. Any pointers on that?

Comment: This would be my guess: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-QAAqsBa3e2Q/Ua90Dq1F5lI/AAAAAAAAC3I/3Ylxg6me9CE/s1600/robocop2-04.jpg